# Visual Studio 2010 new install missing search solution toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Just reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 and the toolbar that lets me search the entire solution is missing and I cannot seem to find the toolbar option of which it is a member.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a custom tool bar and add the find controls to it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a settings issue which persisted across the reinstall.  Try reseting your settings to the default and see if it fixes the problem.

Method 1

- Tools -> Import / Export Settings
- Reset All Settings
- Pick your favorite profile

Method 2

From the Visual Studio command prompt type the following

> devenv.exe /resetsettings

Comment: That did not help.  I am still missing the search toolbar.