# I just can't get the search box to show up on my VS studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I mean what the hell...I've been using this for 7-8 years and now for the first time I accidentally dragged the search box "to hell" (obviously...) so when I click on "find files" or just Ctrl + F it doesn't show me the search box? Yes, restart of VS didn't fix it.

I tried from the top menu too...it tries to show up obviously seeing how the main window loses focus but i just can't see it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 new install missing search solution toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186123/visual-studio-2010-new-install-missing-search-solution-toolbar)

Comment: thanks, i am now resetting to see if this will fix it...

Comment: anyway this didn't fix it but playing with the Window menu did it as I thought...clicking on "dock" menu from "Window" finally showed up, so anyone who misses hiding windows should play a bit with this one from the top menu Window -> Dock or 'reset window document' - but thanks again for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after a clean install of (yes, its 2020 AD) VS Studio 2015.

"Window->Window Layout Reset" did it for me.